# How can I setup notifications when someone connects to my server through SSH?

Tags: ssh, notifications

Is it possible to setup a notifications, i.e. in the form of an email, when someone connects to my server via SSH?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to do this.

Fail2ban is designed to scan log files (e.g. sshd logs and httpd logs) and then ban ip addresses that appear to be behaving maliciously. However, you can reconfigure it to detect successful logins and then e-mail you.